# How to close parent container in extjs

Tags: button, extjs

I tried to close parent window in extjs with `this.up().close()`, but this.$className is undefined.
I am looking for a solution without using Ext.getCmp.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3b4i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want to hide, anyway:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'my Panel',
                html: "Some text.",
                width: 350
            }, {
                xtype: 'box',
                html: '<a href="#" class="link-forgot-password"> Close window</a>',
                listeners: {
                    render: function () {
                        this.getEl().on('click', function () {
                            //this.up('container').hide(); // Hide wrapper container
                            this.previousSibling().hide(); // Hide previous Panel
                        }, this);
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your scope is wrong. You give your element the scope of the application which is the reason why this.up() won't work. If you remove `scope: this` you should be able to use `this.up()` to get the parent container.

I made a fork of your sencha fiddle with a working example:
[Sencha fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3b50)